# Understanding how different methods in OutlineView relate

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble fully understanding all the different places you can return cells when using an OutlineView.  As far as I can tell there are four places:

`NSOutlineViewDataSource` has:

- `outlineView:child`
- `outlineView:objectValueForDataColumn`

And `NSOutlineViewDelegate` has:

- `outlineView:willDisplayCell`
- `outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn`

If I have a outline view with different items, like the SourceList example, where do I do what and why?  I have GroupItem headers and a tree of IconAndImage cells that subclass `NSTextFieldCell`.  Where should these be instantiated and where should I set the styling, image and title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Cocoa means by the word cell is not the same as what you would call a cell in for example Excel.

In Cocoa, a cell is a `NSCell` subclass and could be considered as a light-weight reusable `NSView`. It is used to draw many items in the same way. E.g.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)draw_rect {
    // ...
    for ( id value in myDataArray ) {
        [cell setObjectValue:value];
        NSRect cellFrame = ...;
        [cell drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:self];
    }
```

So a data source does not return cells, but instead return objects that are parameters to `[(NSCell) -(void)setObjectValue:(id)value]`. The delegate returns which cell-object to use for each item and should be implemented so that you only create each cell-type once. E.g.

```
- (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
 dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                   item:(id)item {
    NSCell *cell = nil;
    switch(tableColumn.tag) {
         case 0:
             if  ( ! myCell ) {
                  myCell = [[NSCell alloc] init];
             }
             cell = myCell;
             break;
        default:
             break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

You should use table column tags or a similar feature to handle column re-ordering by the user.